# Cómo utilizar transition con etiqueta span

Tags: html, css, css3, hover, transition

soy nueva en esto de la programación y estoy haciendo un curso de introducción a CSS y HTML.

El caso es que acabo de terminar una lección en la que enseñan el concepto hover y en el ejercicio que proponen me dan un Código html y luego bloques de estilos, y me piden que en el primer bloque añada una transición de 0.7s.

Lo hago y lo rehago y me sigue dando error en el ejercicio, y la verdad es que no sé qué es lo que estoy haciendo mal.

El código que me dan es el siguiente:

```
    <div class="parent">
      <div class="first-child- 
         element">
        <span>Item 1</span>
        <span>Item 2</span>
        <span>Item 3</span>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Y los estilos que me ponen de inicio son:

```
     .parent>.first-child-element> 
      span{
        Width:10px;
        Background-color:green;}

      .parent>.first-child- 
       element> span:hover{
        Color:white;
        }
```

Yo ya he probado de todo, de inicio simplemente puse transition:0,7; debajo de background, y me daba error, y he probado mil cosas y nada.
Alguien que me resuelva la duda?
Gracias!

Comment: Recuerda hacer el [tour] en Stackoverflow para conocer su funcionamie yo y ganar tu primera medalla

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aquí diste un salto de línea en tu clase:

```
<div class="first-child- 
         element">
```

Y esto sería lo mismo que:

```
<div class="first-child- element">
```

También otro error que ví es en tu css está ocurriendo lo mismo:

```
.parent>.first-child- 
       element> span:hover{
        Color:white;
        }
```

Y esto sería lo mismo que:

```
.parent>.first-child- element> span:hover{
        Color:white;
        }
```

De la cual ambas clases son incorrectas, debería ser `first-child-element`. Tu código final vendría a ser así:

```css
.parent > .first-child-element > span {
  width: 10px;
  background-color: green;
  transition: linear 0.7s; /*le aplicamos la transición*/
}

.parent > .first-child-element > span:hover {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="first-child-element">
    <span>Item 1</span>
    <span>Item 2</span>
    <span>Item 3</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Y si quieres darle el estilo solo al primer `nav`, tendrías que agregar la pseudoclase [**`:first-child`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/:first-child):

```css
.parent > .first-child-element > span {
  width: 10px;
  background-color: green;
  transition: linear 0.7s; /*le aplicamos la transición*/
}

.parent > .first-child-element > span:first-child:hover {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="first-child-element">
    <span>Item 1</span>
    <span>Item 2</span>
    <span>Item 3</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta!

Answer (score 0):

Tu problema era que no escribiste bien las clases tanto en CSS y HTML. Por ejemplo, la siguiente tenía un espacio después del segundo guión

```
.first-child- elemen
```

Y este mismo caso, en el HTML, justo ahí tenía un *punto aparte*

Para mejorar tu código y que sea prolijo y que se pueda leer mejor, escribe todo separado por un espacio (como en el snippet), porque esto es solo una práctica. Separa cada palabra del `{` o del `>` y del `:`

```css
            
.parent > .first-child-element > span { 
Width: 10px; 
Background-color: green;
} 

.parent > .first-child-element > span:hover { 
color: white; 
}
```

```html
            
    <div class="parent"> 
        
        <div class="first-child-element"> 
            
            <span>Item 1</span> 
            <span>Item 2</span> 
            <span>Item 3</span> 
            
        </div> 
    </div>
```

Comment: El código está bien, pero al OP le solicitan aplicarle una transición a los `span`.

Comment: Si... Se me olvidó la transición, me limité solo arreglar el CSS

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta!